# How to move jPlayer volume controls?

Tags: css, jplayer

I have an audio jPlayer with the Blue Monday theme. I removed the seek/playback bar, and shrunk the width to remove the excess space.

```
div.jp-audio {
            max-width:275px;
        }
```

Everything looks fine, except the volume controls, which remain in their original locations (which are now outside the player).

[image: Screenshot of misplaced volume controls]

How can I move the volume controls to the left so that they are inside the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `a.jpmute`, `a.jp-unmute` and `div.jp-volume-bar` to the left.

```
div.jp-audio div.jp-type-single a.jp-mute, 
div.jp-audio div.jp-type-single a.jp-unmute{
    margin-left:50px;
}
div.jp-audio div.jp-volume-bar{
    left:167px;
}
```